# Is my machine not powerful enough to handle JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

Is my machine not powerful enough to handle JMeter?

Im running JMeter from my laptop which has the following spec: 
CPU: i5- 2.40GHz 
8GB Ram
500gb HDD

When i get to around 2k virtual users, JMeter seems to run slow and then i seem to get the following results back / errors:

- Connection Reset
- Connect Refused

I have tried to diagnose the issues with the infrastructure teem but can seem to narrow the problem down, is it best to run JMeter from more than one machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check if JMeter has enough headroom to operate:

1. Increase [JMeter HEAP](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#load_test_running) to be around 80% of your total available physical RAM.
2. Make sure to run your test in [non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
3. Disable all [listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) during test execution
4. Review your test and make sure it's compliant with the recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide
5. Set up monitoring of the machine where JMeter is running and observe CPU, RAM, Network and Disk usage during the load test. You can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for this.
6. Start your test with 1 user and gradually increase the load until you reach 2000 users or any of monitored metrics (CPU, RAM, Network, etc.) starts exceeding i.e. 90% of total available capacity, whatever comes the first. If you're lucky enough - you will be able to mimic 2000 users from a single JMeter instance. If not - you will have to consider [Distributed Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

---

It might also be the case you found a performance bottleneck in the application under test, if you're able to kick off 2000 users and JMeter has enough headroom to operate (system is not overloaded) - most probably it is application responding slowly. In this case apply point 5, this time on application under test side and see if the problem is connected with the lack of resources. If not - inspect infrastructure software configuration, database queries, application "heaviest" functions and objects for possible optimisations.